# Would a fork require miners to update software it they mine on a pool?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, ethminer, forks

Would a miner have to update their mining software, such as ethminer, to go on a forked version of the chain? Or is it up to the pool to decide which chain to mine?

Also, if a miner is mining on a pool that chose to stay on the regular chain, is moving to a forking pool the only way to participate in the forked version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pool miner would not have to update their mining software (`ethminer` or equivalent) to go to the forked version of the chain.

It is up to the pool, running the Ethereum node software (`geth`, `parity` or equivalent) to update that software to go to the forked version of the chain.

Moving pools is the only way to participate in the forked version if you are a pool miner and your current pool does not move to the forked version of the Ethereum node software.

Comment: Would be nice to have pools clearly indicate their intentions so.

Comment: Some did add a voting system. I'm happy that I was mining on ethermine. https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/4otpx0/miners_of_ethpool_and_ethermine_please_cast_your/